# How to sort the records if results are in descending order using php?

Tags: php, magento

I want to paginate from the last record if the results are in descending order. how to send the offset and limti to query if the results are in descending order. I have tried with the following code but it is still showing same results. how to send the parameters to query and paginte

```
if($page_limit=="all"){ 
    $collection->getSelect()->limit("", $params['page']);
}else if($params['sort_by']=="desc"){
    $new = ($get_num_rows-1)*$page_limit;
    $collection->getSelect()->limit($page_limit, $new);
} else {
    $new = ($params['page']-1)*$page_limit;
    $collection->getSelect()->limit($page_limit, $new);
}

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
    if($current_page == $i){                
        $paging .= "<li class='association_page current' >".$i."</li>";  
    }else{
        $paging .= "<li class='association_page' >".$i."</li>";  
    }               
}
```

Comment: getselect is select query

Comment: It is not vanilla PHP so please add it to your code. Or tag your question with whichever framework you are using